# Can I export points along a bezier curve into Unity?

Tags: unity, bezier-curves

I'm trying to export x number of points along a bezier curve as objects in Unity (Think waypoints on a racetrack defined by the curve). I've tried using dupliframes to make duplicate empty objects along the curve. This seems to work how I want, except that while all the objects are exported into unity, they are all placed at the same point based on the curve's evaluation time. Selecting "Make Duplicates Real" fixes that problem, but it essentially stops me from further editing the curve without completely redoing the whole process.

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to achieve the same result? The only other solution I've come up with is to create x number of empty objects and manually set their position along the curve with a Follow Path constraint, which isn't particularly efficient and seems like a pain if I decide to change the number of points.

Comment: Never exported to Unity myself, but the first option seems like the most reliable method. Only thing I'd do differently is to *Make Duplicates Real* on a copy (of the single curve object, or possibly the whole scene is just easier) instead, export from that copy, and keep the originals safe for further editing.